# R ReConstruct DataFrame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
data1=data.frame("grade"=c(rep(1:3,6)),
                "class" = c(rep(c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3)),3)),
"score"=c(rep(c('p','p','p','s','s','s','q','q','q'),2)),
"p"=c(-9:8),
"s"=c(1:18),
"q"=c(21:38))


data2=data.frame("grade"=c(rep(1:3,6)),
                  "class" = c(rep(rep('a',3),rep('b',3),3)),
                "pp"=c(-9,-8,-7,0,1,2),
                "ps"=c(1,2,3,10,11,12),
                "pq"=c(21,22,23,30,31,32),
                "sp"=c(-6,-5,-4,3,4,5),
                "ss"=c(4,5,6,13,14,15),
                "sq"=c(24,25,26,33,34,35),
                "qp"=c(-3,-2,-1,6,7,8),
                "qs"=c(7,8,9,16,17,18),
                "qq"=c(27,28,29,36,37,38))
```

What I have is data1 and I want to make data2. My english is not so good and so I made these two example data frames to show what I wish for. Basically to combine 'score' from 'data1' with column names 'p' and 'q' and 'q' from data1 to create 'data2'.

I have big student district data so wish for a fast data.table solution if it is possible. Also am interested to see dplyr or other simple solution!

Then I wonder how to ggplot all columns of 'data2' [pp-qq] by grade AND 'class'

dcast(setDT(data1), grade + class + rowid(score) ~ score,
      value.var = c('p', 's', 'q'), sep="")[, score := NULL][]

[image]

Hopeful output in two steps, ultimate wish is one on bottom, one on top is intermediate-

[image]

**_____________________________________________________________________________**
A member gave me a very great answer on recasting the dataframe:

```
data1=data.frame("grade"=c(rep(1:3,6)),
                 "class" = c(rep(c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3)),3)),
                 "score"=c(rep(c('p','p','p','s','s','s','q','q','q'),2)),
                 "p"=c(-9:8),
                 "s"=c(1:18),
                 "q"=c(21:38))


d2=dcast(melt(setDT(data1), id.var = 1:3)[, c('score', 'variable') := 
                                         lapply(.SD, function(x) setNames(c(3, 5, 9), c('p', 's', 'q'))[x]),
                                       .SDcols = c('score', 'variable')],grade + class ~ 
        paste0('x', score, variable), value.var = 'value')
```

It works perfect. In my application however I have many more variables. When I go to even add just 1 I break it:

```
data1=data.frame("col1"=c(1),
  "grade"=c(rep(1:3,6)),
                 "class" = c(rep(c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3)),3)),
                 "score"=c(rep(c('p','p','p','s','s','s','q','q','q'),2)),
                 "p"=c(-9:8),
                 "s"=c(1:18),
                 "q"=c(21:38))


d2=dcast(melt(setDT(data1), id.var = 1:3)[, c('score', 'variable') := 
                                         lapply(.SD, function(x) setNames(c(3, 5, 9), c('p', 's', 'q'))[x]),
                                       .SDcols = c('score', 'variable')], col1 + grade + class ~ 
        paste0('x', score, variable), value.var = 'value')
```

> Error in [.data.table(melt(setDT(data1), id.var = 1:3), ,
>   :=(c("score", : Some items of .SDcols are not column names: [score] In
>   addition: Warning message: In melt.data.table(setDT(data1), id.var =
>   1:3) : 'measure.vars' [score, p, s, q] are not all of the same type.
>   By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type
>   'character'. All measure variables not of type 'character' will be
>   coerced too. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.

Maybe there is a way to do it less likely to break? Your aid is much appreciated!

Comment: @akrun any thoughts?

Comment: @Ronak Shah any thoughts?

Comment: Are those values x53, x35 interchanged

Comment: I do not believe so.

Comment: I see some values not correct.  Can you please check in the expected

Comment: I think you need the index `id.var = 1:4`. With that change, it works for me

Comment: @akrun I AM INDEBTED TO YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
data1 %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(score)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = score, values_from = c('p', 's', 'q'), 
         names_sep="") %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
#  grade class    pp    ps    pq    sp    ss    sq    qp    qs    qq
#  <int> <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 a        -9    -6    -3     1     4     7    21    24    27
#2     2 a        -8    -5    -2     2     5     8    22    25    28
#3     3 a        -7    -4    -1     3     6     9    23    26    29
#4     1 a         0     3     6    10    13    16    30    33    36
#5     2 a         1     4     7    11    14    17    31    34    37
#6     3 a         2     5     8    12    15    18    32    35    38
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data1), grade + class + rowid(score) ~ score,
     value.var = c('p', 's', 'q'), sep="")[, score := NULL][]
#   grade class pp pq ps sp sq ss qp qq qs
#1:     1     a -9 -3 -6  1  7  4 21 27 24
#2:     1     a  0  6  3 10 16 13 30 36 33
#3:     2     a -8 -2 -5  2  8  5 22 28 25
#4:     2     a  1  7  4 11 17 14 31 37 34
#5:     3     a -7 -1 -4  3  9  6 23 29 26
#6:     3     a  2  8  5 12 18 15 32 38 35
```

If we want to replace the column names, use a named vector to match and replace

```
out <- dcast(setDT(data1), grade + class + rowid(score) ~ 
      setNames(c(33, 55, 99), c('p', 's', 'q'))[score],
     value.var = c('p', 's', 'q'), sep="")[, score := NULL][]
setnames(out, 3:ncol(out), sub("^.", "x", names(out)[3:ncol(out)]))
out
#   grade class x33 x55 x99 x33 x55 x99 x33 x55 x99
#1:     1     a  -9  -3  -6   1   7   4  21  27  24
#2:     1     a   0   6   3  10  16  13  30  36  33
#3:     2     a  -8  -2  -5   2   8   5  22  28  25
#4:     2     a   1   7   4  11  17  14  31  37  34
#5:     3     a  -7  -1  -4   3   9   6  23  29  26
#6:     3     a   2   8   5  12  18  15  32  38  35
```

---

For the updated example, we need to get the sequence by 'class' as well

```
out <- dcast(setDT(data1), grade + class + rowid(class, score) ~ 
       setNames(c(33, 55, 99), c('p', 's', 'q'))[score],
      value.var = c('p', 's', 'q'), sep="")[, class1 := NULL][]
setnames(out, 3:ncol(out), sub("^.", "x", names(out)[3:ncol(out)]))
out
#   grade class x33 x55 x99 x33 x55 x99 x33 x55 x99
#1:     1     a  -9  -3   3   1   7  13  21  27  33
#2:     1     b   0   6  -6  10  16   4  30  36  24
#3:     2     a  -8  -2   4   2   8  14  22  28  34
#4:     2     b   1   7  -5  11  17   5  31  37  25
#5:     3     a  -7  -1   5   3   9  15  23  29  35
#6:     3     b   2   8  -4  12  18   6  32  38  26
```

#### Update

```
setDT(data1)[, score := setNames(c(3, 5, 9), c('p', 's', 'q'))[score]]
setnames(data1, c('p', 's', 'q'), as.character(c(3, 5, 9)))
out <-  dcast(setDT(data1), grade + class + rowid(class, score) ~ score,
     value.var = c('3', '5', '9'), sep="")[, class1 := NULL][]
setnames(out, 3:ncol(out), paste0("x", names(out)[3:ncol(out)]))
```

---

Or another option is `melt/dcast`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(data1), id.var = 1:3)[, c('score', 'variable') := 
 lapply(.SD, function(x) setNames(c(3, 5, 9), c('p', 's', 'q'))[x]),
 .SDcols = c('score', 'variable')], grade + class ~ 
     paste0('x', score, variable), value.var = 'value')
#   grade class x33 x35 x39 x53 x55 x59 x93 x95 x99
#1:     1     a  -9   1  21  -3   7  27   3  13  33
#2:     1     b   0  10  30   6  16  36  -6   4  24
#3:     2     a  -8   2  22  -2   8  28   4  14  34
#4:     2     b   1  11  31   7  17  37  -5   5  25
#5:     3     a  -7   3  23  -1   9  29   5  15  35
#6:     3     b   2  12  32   8  18  38  -4   6  26
```

Comment: @bvowe i also posted a solution to your other question with `cumsum`. could be. useful for you

Comment: thank you a bunch! I actually try your data.table solution and it gives me some 'NA'

Comment: @bvowe Is it based on the same example here as I couldn't reproduce it

Comment: @bvowe it is the sequence issue as the 'class' have more valuese in the new example.  Updated

Comment: ah! apologies!! it is perfect now

Comment: I spoke a tad early but all my fault! I meant to specify that the new column names should follow where  p = 3 and s = 5 and q = 9. so pp = x33; ps = x35; sq = 59 and so on I am sorry!

Comment: @bvowe can you please updatee your post with expected output as it is not clear to me

Comment: updated thank you so much. i am working to improve my question asking and i thank you for all the patience!

Comment: ah I see, that is a very nice answer. I find it useful ;)

Comment: I think i broke something. I just restarted my computer and when I run your code under bolded "Update" I get:: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @bvowe Please use the `melt/dcast` one instead of the first one as that I created before understanding the full issue

Comment: perfect! thanks again, you truly are incredibly helpful. I am learning a lot!

Comment: please note the update if you have a chance! @akrun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209647/discussion-between-bvowe-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

You can use base function `reshape` for this.

I needed to add an extra variable (`unique`) to discriminate the first 9 from the second 9 rows in `data1`.  You could delete this afterwards if you don't need it.

```
data1$unique <- rep(1:2, each=9)

reshape(data=data1, 
        direction="wide",
        v.names=c("p","s","q"),
        timevar="score",
        idvar=c("grade","class","unique"),
        sep="")

   grade class unique pp sp qp ps ss qs pq sq qq
1      1     a      1 -9  1 21 -6  4 24 -3  7 27
2      2     a      1 -8  2 22 -5  5 25 -2  8 28
3      3     a      1 -7  3 23 -4  6 26 -1  9 29
10     1     a      2  0 10 30  3 13 33  6 16 36
11     2     a      2  1 11 31  4 14 34  7 17 37
12     3     a      2  2 12 32  5 15 35  8 18 38
```

Comment: Thank you greatly, now say i want to represent the v.names with numbers so p = 3 and s = 5 and q = 9. so instead of pp ps pq for example i have x33 x35 x39? in order? @George Savva